# Can't call Js function in Jquery from Hotkeyplugin

Tags: javascript

https://github.com/tzuryby/jquery.hotkeys

My code should now focus on the input field with the id "form".

if I change it to alert("hi"); it works but if I just do focusinput, it does nothing...

why?
How can i do this operation and bind the keys "ctrl+k" to focus on the input field?

```
function focusinput() {
    document.getElementById("form").focus();
}

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(document).bind('keyup', 'ctrl+k', function() {
        focusinput();
    });
});

</script>

<input id="form" name="form" type="text">
```

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: Your code seems to work when I try it here http://jsfiddle.net/XQTaJ/ Focuses in on the input fine, what browser are you using

Comment: No error at all, i use Firefox